# Импорты в питоне

Tags: python

Есть первый модуль, под названием А. В него я импортировал какие либо модули. После чего в модуле Б импортировал модуль А. Импортировались ли также те импорты, которые были импортированы в модуль А?

*A.py*

```
from pprint import pprint
```

*B.py*

```
import A
```

Answer (score 2):

Напрямую к импортированным модулям в файле b из файла a вы обратиться не можете.

Пример:

**b.py**

```
import datetime
```

**a.py**

```
import b

print(dir())  # видно что библиотеки datetime нет
print(dir(b)) 

print(datetime.time())  #  Ошибка
print(b.datetime.time())  # Работает корректно
```

Однако, если вы например создадите свой класс использующий библиотечную функцию, в файле b.py, то можно обратиться через него, минуя прямой импорт библиотеки

**b.py**

```
import datetime

class Time:
    def get_time(self=None):
        return datetime.time()
```

**a.py**

```
from b import Time

print(Time.get_time())  # Работает
```

Answer (score 2):

Образно работает так:

1. Выполняются затронутые модули - все `__init__.py` по пути и сам модуль выполняется. Выполнение кода в файле модуля происходит сверху вниз - и рождает классы, функции, *производит импорты* и т.д. В результате выполнения у каждого выполненного модуля заполняется пространство имен.
2. Происходит импорт чего-то из этого пространства имен модуля-источника в пространство имен вашего модуля под каким-то именем. То есть "что-то из чужого пространство имен будет доступна мне под таким вот именем". Хоть вообще всё чужое пространство имен.

В других языках вида пхп можно сделать include и глобальное пространство имен замусорится новыми элементами и их можно вызывать. В python пространство имен каждого модуля изолировано и нужно явно его заполнить для последующей работы с элементами.

Поэтому сначала нужно **положить это в наше пространство имен найдя его в чужом пространстве имен, или само чужое пространство имен сделать доступным под нужным именем**. Это и делает импорт. После этого мы можем работать с этим под нужным именем.

И не имеет значения откуда элемент появился в чужом пространстве имен. Для импорта это просто "вот это у тебя с этим именем вот сюда мне под этим именем сделай доступным"
(поэтому многочисленные `from typing import ...` в чужом модуле замусоривают подсказку IDE - такова уж специфика)

```
from pprint import pprint
```

поместил функцию `pprint` в пространство имен модуля A (под этим же именем `pprint`)

ваш `import A` просто делает доступным пространство имен этого модуля через A и вы можете вызвать `A.pprint(...`

Но сам `pprint` не попадает автоматом в пространство имен модуля B. **Вы должны явно задавать что из чужого модуля вы хотите сделать видимым у себя и под каким именем.**

Исключение вот такой импорт, который все же явный

```
from A import *
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, файлы импортируются.
Это проверяется крайне легко.
Правда постарайтесь избежать цикличного импорта.

Если вам понадобится какой либо конкретный импорт из файла `A`, можно импортировать точечно:

```
from A import name
```

Если же вам нужны все функции просто сделайте импорт файла и обращайтесь напрямую:

```
import A
```